# HTML CSS horizontal scrolling doesn't work at all

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with html/css. I tried to make a horizontally-scrolled list of divs, but all solutions I found on Stack Overflow was failed. Setting `overflow-x: scroll;` gives an inactive scrollbar and all elements that don't fit are moved to 2nd line. I tried to put all divs in a container, but it doesn't work. I attached a [picture that describes what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuejd.png). Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 90px 0 0 0;
}

#belka_up {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 57px;
  height: 70px;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.karta {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

h1,
.cena {
  padding: 10px;
}

.cena {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.karta button {
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 200ms;
}

.karta button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.kontener {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 627px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="belka_up"><b> BUCZI </b></div>
<div class="kontener">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/cz_bi_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza cz_bi_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <h1>Bluza Classic Invert czarna</h1>
        <p class="cena">29,99,-</p>
        <p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p>
      </div>.
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/bi_cz_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza bi_cz_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <h1>Bluza Classic Invert biała</h1>
        <p class="cena">29,99,-</p>
        <p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p>
      </div>.
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/cz_bi_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza cz_bi_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <h1>Bluza Classic Invert czarna</h1>
        <p class="cena">29,99,-</p>
        <p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p>
      </div>.
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/bi_cz_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza bi_cz_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <h1>Bluza Classic Invert biała</h1>
        <p class="cena">29,99,-</p>
        <p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p>
      </div>.
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/cz_bi_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza cz_bi_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <h1>Bluza Classic Invert czarna</h1>
        <p class="cena">29,99,-</p>
        <p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p>
      </div>.
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/bi_cz_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza bi_cz_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
        <h1>Bluza Classic Invert biała</h1>
        <p class="cena">29,99,-</p>
        <p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p>
      </div>.
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: set `overflow-x: auto` instead of `scroll`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set the width of the scrollable container to be smaller than it's contents.  In your case the .kontener should be 100% perhaps.  Then you need to set a larger width for it's child object, in this case the ul.  I have put some fixed values but you would probably want it to me a bit more dynamic for a real world solution.

```css
body {
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 margin: 90px 0 0 0;
}
#belka_up {
    background-color: #FFF;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
 font-family: serif;
    font-size: 57px;
    height: 70px;
 left: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.karta {
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 max-width: 300px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #FFF;
}
h1, .cena { 
 padding: 10px;
}
.cena {
 color: grey;
 font-size: 22px;
}
.karta button {
 background-color: #000;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 12px;
 outline: 0;
 padding: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 transition: 200ms;
}
.karta button:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
li {
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.kontener{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
.kontener ul{
width: 1920px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> @pagename </title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet"> 
<meta name="theme-color" content="#F00">
</head>
<body>
<div id="belka_up"><b> BUCZI </b></div>
<div class="kontener">
<ul>
<li>
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/cz_bi_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza cz_bi_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert czarna</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/bi_cz_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza bi_cz_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert biała</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/cz_bi_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza cz_bi_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert czarna</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/bi_cz_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza bi_cz_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert biała</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/cz_bi_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza cz_bi_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert czarna</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/bi_cz_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza bi_cz_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert biała</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much as it looks exactly as I imagined that :D

Answer (score 0):

you could use display: flex for the ul element.
Ofcourse you would need some more styling, I just changed a few properties here and marked them. I also set the width of the container to 500px but don't let that bother you...

```css
body {
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 10px;
 margin: 90px 0 0 0;
}
#belka_up {
    background-color: #FFF;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #000;
    display: inline-block;
 font-family: serif;
    font-size: 57px;
    height: 70px;
 left: 0;
    line-height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
.karta {
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 max-width: 300px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #FFF;
}
h1, .cena { 
 padding: 10px;
}
.cena {
 color: grey;
 font-size: 22px;
}
.karta button {
 background-color: #000;
 border: none;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 12px;
 outline: 0;
 padding: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 transition: 200ms;
}
.karta button:hover {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
li {
 float: left;
 padding: 10px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

/* Changes begin here */
.kontener{
    width: 500px;
    height: 627px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
 float: left;
 
}

.kontener > ul {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
 overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl-PL">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> @pagename </title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet"> 
<meta name="theme-color" content="#F00">
</head>
<body>
<div id="belka_up"><b> BUCZI </b></div>
<div class="kontener">
<ul>
<li>
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/cz_bi_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza cz_bi_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert czarna</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/bi_cz_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza bi_cz_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert biała</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/cz_bi_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza cz_bi_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert czarna</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/bi_cz_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza bi_cz_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert biała</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/cz_bi_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza cz_bi_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert czarna</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
<li> 
 <div class="karta"> <img src="produkty/bluzy/bi_cz_cl_01.jpg" alt="Bluza bi_cz_cl_01" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;">
 <h1>Bluza Classic Invert biała</h1> <p class="cena">29,99,-</p><p><button>Dodaj do koszyka</button></p> </div>.
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```